# Moving examples… what just happened?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, move-examples

I moved some examples from Subquery (deleted by move) to [Subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/1606/subqueries), and when I viewed the draft for Subqueries, it added "Moved from Subquery.Moved from Subquery.Moved from Subquery.Moved from Subquery." to each of the examples I **didn't** move. (and shorter versions above the ones I did move.

[image: Screenshot]

So… what just happened here?

Comment: I think I reproduced this by moving several examples and then editing the draft of the destination topic. By experimenting a little, it appears the "Moved from X." string is added once to the last example, twice to the second-to-last and so on up to the number of examples you moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened!

Or more specifically, I removed the code we used to render the vertical split view a few days ago, and in the process used the wrong variable when looking up the container to place the "Moved from X" notification in.

Just pushed a fix, and it will go live with the next production build.

Thanks for the report!